# Access parent DevExpress Popup from within iframe

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I am within an HTML iframe and am trying to access a DevExpress popup window which is on the main parent window.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

I've tried window.parent.document but can only access html elements. I would like to access the popup window with is properties and methods.

Comment: i've also tried self.parent.opener which returned null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out!
For those of you haveing a simialr issue - it's the same as any html.
window.parent.DEVEXPRESSclientInstanceName.
i was getting confused because regular html you get with document.getElementByID() but a control in devexpress just simply call the clientInstanceName.

Thanks.